# Why does form-group offset row?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using form-group in Bootstrap 3.  It is causing some horizontal alignment issues.

Here's an example of what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/7723q8kr/. Notice columns 3 and 4 are lower than 1 and 2.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class='row'>
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-3">Hi</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">Hi</div>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-3">Hi</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">Hi</div>
        </div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-3">Hi</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">Hi</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-3">Hi</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">Hi</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-3">Hi</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">Hi</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-3">Hi</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">Hi</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

When form-group is removed, as shown here http://jsfiddle.net/1kL4tfux/, the problem goes away.

Is there a way to use form-group within this context and not have it affect alignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any `col` class divs in Bootstrap have a float applied. But the `form-group` is a `block` element, which by default will take up 100% width. It also has a `margin-bottom` property which will push the next divs down. This causes the form group items to stack (which is what it is intended to do).

You can wrap them in a `form-inline` element. But you lose a bit of your formatting, so you'd need to specify the width of the `form-group`. As the Bootstrap documentation says:

> Requires custom widths
>
> Inputs and selects have width: 100%; applied by
>   default in Bootstrap. Within inline forms, we reset that to width:
>   auto; so multiple controls can reside on the same line. Depending on
>   your layout, additional custom widths may be required.

So you could do something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/7723q8kr/1/

Comment: Thanks.  I don't think you specific the width in that example?  I'm overriding by using .form-group {width:350px;}.  That should work fine right?

Comment: @4thSpace Oh, I used `col-xs-6` so the width would be 50% (and overrice the `width:auto`.

Comment: For four columns, should I specify a fixed width via the override example I provided above or do something different?

Comment: @4thSpace I would avoid fixed width as you lose all boostrap responsiveness.